# Wrong cv::face FacemarkLBF instantiation

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection

I am using OpenCV 4.4.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 with the installed latest *opencv_contrib* extra modules. For detecting the face landmarks (based on [this](https://www.learnopencv.com/facemark-facial-landmark-detection-using-opencv/) tutorial) I use the following #include and namespace sections related to the extra *face* module :

```
#include <opencv2/face.hpp>
using namespace cv::face;
```

The face.hpp file is detected (therefore I assume correct installation of the *opencv_contrib* modules), but e.g. the line

```
    Ptr<facemark> facemark = FacemarkLBF::create();
```

throws an error

```
error: ‘facemark’ was not declared in this scope
```

I have already tried installing the extra modules with both cmake-gui and with the cmake terminal command. The results are the same. I assume there is an error related to the *namespace cv::face*. Any ideas on what kind of mistake I am doing here?

The minimal code is here:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/face.hpp>
#include "drawLandmarks.hpp"


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::face;


int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    // Load Face Detector
    CascadeClassifier faceDetector("haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");

    // Create an instance of Facemark
    Ptr<facemark> facemark = FacemarkLBF::create();

    // Load landmark detector
    facemark->loadModel("lbfmodel.yaml");

    // Set up webcam for video capture
    VideoCapture cam(0);
    
    // Variable to store a video frame and its grayscale 
    Mat frame, gray;
    
    // Read a frame
    while(cam.read(frame))
    {
      
      // Find face
      vector<rect> faces;
      // Convert frame to grayscale because
      // faceDetector requires grayscale image.
      cvtColor(frame, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

      // Detect faces
      faceDetector.detectMultiScale(gray, faces);
      
      // Variable for landmarks. 
      // Landmarks for one face is a vector of points
      // There can be more than one face in the image. Hence, we 
      // use a vector of vector of points. 
      vector< vector<point2f> > landmarks;
      
      // Run landmark detector
      bool success = facemark->fit(frame,faces,landmarks);
      
      if(success)
      {
        // If successful, render the landmarks on the face
        for(int i = 0; i < landmarks.size(); i++)
        {
          drawLandmarks(frame, landmarks[i]);
        }
      }

      // Display results 
      imshow("Facial Landmark Detection", frame);
      // Exit loop if ESC is pressed
      if (waitKey(1) == 27) break;
      
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `facemark` is either a type or the name of your varaible. It cant be both

Comment: I'm not familar with this but `Ptr<facemark> facemark` is very strange. Maybe it should be `Ptr<FacemarkLBF> facemark` but I'm just guessing.

Comment: typo? perhaps you want  a `Ptr<FacemarkLBF>` ?

Comment: See here https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d63/classcv_1_1face_1_1FacemarkLBF.html `Ptr<FacemarkLBF>` is correct.

Comment: @john That is indeed correct, I had not checked the cv::face::FacemarkLBF Class  and wrongly assumed it was a face module problem. Thank you for your help, I will answer my question so it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

As @john and  @idclev 463035818 have suggested, the way for creating an instance of Facemark is

```
Ptr<FacemarkLBF> facemark = FacemarkLBF::create();
```

e.g. if I want to call it facemark.

Comment: Another method that works is to use `auto` to get the compiler to work out the type for you `auto facemark = FacemarkLBF::create();`. Still it's a good idea to know what the correct type is just in case you need it.